# jQuery object method executing on ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I am building a MVC framework client-side using javascript that mirrors the server-side Rails MVC. The system I building makes frequent AJAX calls and sends jQuery objects that are defined in the model files.

The problem I am running into is that the model objects have methods attached to them and when jQuery sends them through AJAX it executes every method in the object.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and a way to prevent it?

#### Example Model

```js
var search = function (){
    this.id = null;
    this.investor = null;
    this.program = null;
    this.parent = null;
    this.client = null;
    this.date = null;
    this.custom_order = "custom_order";
    this.data_set = "all";
    this.recursive = false;
    this.search = null;
    this.state_filter = PUB | DRAFT;

    this.message = function()
    {
        alert("Message");
    }
}
```

#### Example Controller

```js
var nav_object = {search: System.search, page: System.page};
            $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              url: "/guidelines/search",
              data: nav_object,
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(data){
                //Success
                if(data.errors)
                {
                    alert(data.errors.message);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.guidelines.search = data.guidelines;
                    System.page = data.page;
                    System.meta.searchState = false;
                    loadView();
                }
              }
            });
```

In the example above System.search is an instance of the search class. When that is inserted into the the nav_object and sent to the server the message function is ran.

I know I could pull out the members of the class and build a new object before I send it I just feel like thats a lot of code that could be avoided.

Comment: Hi, I don´t know an approach but I got some advice maybe. You receive program code with a GET request. This is a security problem.
Imagine a bad person faking that request having access to sensible data. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In this case the GET is pulling internal data that first requires authentication and has no access to sensitive information. Using the GET in this case is to prevent someone from changing database information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a wrapper function you can selectively choose what gets sent into the ajax call. This separates the function from the data. You may also want to prototype the function so that it is not redefined everywhere it is used.